# C# Use of Unassigned local variables what is reason

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0, local-variables

```
namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int x, y;
            //    Console.WriteLine("Enter the first number is" + x + "enter Secnd number is" + y);

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the first number");
                x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("invalid input " +e);
            }

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the Second number");
                y = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());                  
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ivalid input"+e);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the first number is: x =" +x + "enter Secnd number is: y=" + y);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if `int.Parse()` throws an exception, the code carries on and tries to use the variable farther down. To fix it, you could add a `return;` statement at the end of your `catch` blocks. Not the most ideal solution, but it will fix the error. You could also just assign `x` and `y` initial values (0 maybe?) when you declare them.

Comment: It's unlikely that `Console.WriteLine()` would throw an exception - it is more likely that `int.Parse` would throw.

Comment: @BJMyers Thanks, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize Your vars With 0 .. Or Put The Whole Code in One Try Catch Block

Answer (score 0):

As other people have indicated, you try to print `x` and `y` at the end regardless of whether the assignment in the try/catch block worked. You could try to keep prompting the user until they enter valid input.

Also, a format string or string interpolation may be better at the end.